# Trying to draw a image on screen using pygame, but the screen is blank?

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

I'm still fairly new to Python and programming in general.  I am attempting to follow along with a book I am using in order to create a simple game.  I have typed the program up verbatim as far as I can tell, but for whatever reason everything seems fine except my ship image does not appear.  Does anyone see what the problem may be?  I am using Python 3.4.3 with the corresponding pygame version.

```
#Creating a pygame window and responding to user input

import sys

import pygame

def bg_draw():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

                pygame.display.flip()

bg_draw()

#Setting the bg color

def bg_color():
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')

    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    while True:
        screen.fill(bg_color)

        pygame.display.flip()

bg_color()


from settings import Settings

def run_settings():
    #initializes pygame, settings, and screen object
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    #start main loop for game

    while True:
        #redraws screen during each pass through the loop
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()

run_settings()



#Creating the ship class


class ship():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        #load ship image and get it's rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        #start a new ship at bottom of screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


#drawing the ship on the screen


def run_game():
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    #makes a ship
    ship = Ship(screen)

    #start games main loop
    while True:
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Comment: where is `Ship()` class and `blitme()` method ? BTW `ship()` and `Ship()` is not the same class - you should get error message. Did you run it in console/termina/cmd.exe/powershell to see error messages ?

Comment: you have too many `while True` loops. You run first loop in `bg_draw()` and you never leave it.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `while True` loops. You run `bg_draw()` so you run first `while True` and you never leave it.

Besides `ship()` and `Ship()` is not the same class, the same with `settings()` and `Settings()`

Your code could look like this

```
# --- all import at the beginning ---
import sys
import pygame
#from settings import Settings

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

#WIDTH = 1200
#HEIGHT = 800
#GREY = (230, 230, 230)

FPS = 30

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Settings():

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

class Ship():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        #load ship image and get it's rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        #start a new ship at bottom of screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def run_game(screen, ai_settings):

    #makes a ship
    ship = Ship(screen)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #start games main loop
    while True:
        # --- events ---
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # exit on close window
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

            # exit on press button ESC
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

        # --- updates ---

        #empty

        # --- draws ---

        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.draw()
        pygame.display.flip()

        # --- FPS ---

        #control game speed
        clock.tick(FPS)

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

ai_settings = Settings()

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

run_game(screen, ai_settings)

pygame.quit()
```